# MIPS - help converting code from C

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I am a beginner in MIPS and I am trying to write a simple code that runs over a given array in memory that is smaller than 10 cells, lets say 9 cells, and prints on screen the biggest number.

I wrote a C code that solves this issue, but I don't know how to convert it (without mips gcc) to a working MIPS assembly code.

The code I wrote:

```
int N = 9 , i = 0 , biggest = 0 ;
int arr [N] = -2 , 3 , 9 , -1 , 5 , 6 , 10 , 52 , 9 ;

while ( i <= N )
{
    if ( arr [i] > biggest )
        biggest = arr [i] ;

    i++ ;
}

printf ( "biggest number is: %d" , biggest ) ;
```

I will be more than happy if someone can write that code in MIPS assembly, and explain it to me.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just focusing on the loop, try something like that:

```
   .text
   .set noreorder
   .global get_max
get_max:
   li    $4, array               // start pointer
   li    $5, array_end-array-4   // end pointer
   li    $2, 0                   // 'biggest' as result
   lw    $6, 0($4)               // load first table entry
1: slt   $3, $2, $6              // boolean flag (biggest<arr[i])
   movn  $2, $6, $3              // update 'biggest' when flag is set
   lw    $6, 4($4)               // load next table entry
   bne   $4, $5, 1b              // continue until we hit end of array
   addiu $4, 4                   // advance to next cell (using bne delay slot)
   jr    $31                     // return to the caller
   nop                           // safely fill the delay slot

           .data
array:     .long -2 , 3 , 9 , -1 , 5 , 6 , 10 , 52 , 9 
array_end: .long 0
```

Compile this into a separate assembly source file and link with your main C code.

Don't forget to call the function from your C code:

```
printf("biggest=%d\n",get_max());
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer !

What do you mean by: "note that you need to set noreorder directive to get it work" ?
did you mean that it should be like this:
        .text
 .globl __start
__start:
        li $t4 array
        li $t5 array_end
        li $t2 0
        lw $s6 0($t4)
      1:slt $s3 $s2 $s6
        movn $s2 $s6 $s3
        lw $s6 4($s4)
        bne $s4 $s5 1b
        addiu $s4 4

        .data
array:     .long -2 , 3 , 9 , -1 , 5 , 6 , 10 , 52 , 9 
array_end: .long 0

Comment: I can't write a normal code reply.... can you write the complete program as it should be ? I just need to see how its run, and also how do I add a print on screen the biggest number ?

thnx !!

Comment: I can't write the whole program for you, because I don't know your exec environment. If you're interested in seeing code run, write C, use objdump to disassemble and try to understand what's going on there. If you get stuck, copy-paste an excerpt of the assembly and ask for explanation. I don't care to write assembly that call printf (C compiler does that better than I do), only the loop is worth to be hand written (here I can do much better than the compiler)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your initialization...